# Cartesian Product with constraints

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a really big database that I have to sort and divide as the example below:

```
            F1  F2  F3      C1  C2  C3  C4      results         

    P1      X       X       X   X   X           P1  F1  C1  

    P2      X       X           X       X       P1  F3  C1  

    P3          X           X       X           P1  F1  C2  

                                                P1  F3  C2  

                                                P1  F1  C3  

                                                P1  F3  C2  

                                                P2  F1  C2
```

I think it has something to do with Cartesian product but I really don't know how to give some sort of constraints (the X are the one that matches).

Comment: i can't share the database but my problem is that i have to match one value with two other values like 
if P1 was "cat" , F1 was the verb, and C1 is the object. my problem is that i have to form all the possible phrases that matches with "cat" adding F1 and P1.

All the results have to be in different rows (like in the example below).

Comment: My real problem is that i can't just match all the P with all the F and all the C (because I would just do P*F*C) but P doesn't mach with all the F and with all the C. 
Every P matches with at least one F and one C but for every P there are something like 1500 P and 100F and 100C i can't do all the matches by hand, i was hoping to find a formula to solve it.

Comment: no the problem was exactly that i can't do like this P,F,C are always in the same position

Comment: all the matches have to follow a schedule as you can see in the table up there

Comment: not ALL possible combos, but all the combos that fit with my rules (for example:
Does P1 match with F1?And with C1?==>yes?= P1+F1+C1==>No?=P1+F(the one that matches)+C(the one that matches))

Comment: in the sheet above there are examples of when P match with only some F or C (Check the X mark)

Comment: actually thik like all the P are names, all the F are one thing they can do and C think is their work. 
The only result i need is to match them as i told you following a schema.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Npgpihw-1ulAHryqc0ONLtLbrz7cpfA2iAQfchvSjBA/edit?usp=sharing

see if can this maybe canhelp you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saem, assuming your label "P1" is in A2, your label "F1" is in B1, and your label "C1" is in F1, the following array formula should give the results you want:

`=ArrayFormula({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("\", TRUE, IF(B2:D4="x", REPT(A2:A4&" "&B1:D1&"\", MMULT(N(F2:I4="x"), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(F1:I1)^0))), "")), "\")), " "), TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", REPT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F2:I4="x", F1:I1, "")), , COLUMNS(IF(F2:I4="x", F1:I1, "")))))&" ", MMULT(N(B2:D4="x"), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:D4)^0)))), " "))})`

You should be able to have a scope of any size and just replace the corresponding ranges to get a complete list.

Comment: Thank you so much Erik! It works perfecly and fit great to what i want to do!

Comment: Happy to help, Saem. If you would, please mark my formula as the correct answer. It helps the community here see at a glance which issues have been fully addressed, so that others don't continue to try to add suggestions unnecessarily. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Erik, actually i have some issues ; i'm running this code
 =ArrayFormula({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("\", TRUE, IF($B$2:$CA$425="x", REPT($A$2:$A$425&" "&$B$1:$CA$1&"\", MMULT(N($CC$2:$HB$425="x"), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($CC$1:$HB$1)^0))), "")), "\")), " "), TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", REPT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF($CC$2:$HB$425="x", $CC$1:$HB$1, "")), , COLUMNS(IF($CC$2:$HB$425="x", $CC$1:$HB$1, "")))))&" ", MMULT(N($B$2:$CA$425="x"), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B$2:$CA$425)^0)))), " "))})
 that is exactly like your but it gives me a "Function Array_Row has mismatched row size"

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is taking out all of the dollar signs. Beyond that, I'd need to see it in context. Feel free to share a link with editing permissions.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Npgpihw-1ulAHryqc0ONLtLbrz7cpfA2iAQfchvSjBA/edit#gid=0

i did as you said, feel free to edit and comment i'll be happy to learn more.
there are 425 "P" , all the "F" are the datas before CA and all the datas after CC are the "C". the formula was in HC2 cell

Comment: Saem, the TEXTJOIN function in Google Sheets has a limit of 50000 characters that it can hold at any one time. You are trying to process a huge amount of information, which is exceeding that 50000-character limit. So before the first part of the entire formula is even done, an error is being thrown (resulting in one cell's worth of "data": the error). That means the second half of the formula, which includes over 6700 results, has nothing to match with.

Comment: It is always best to share the parameters of your END data from the start. For instance, had I known your actual data would be this expansive, I wouldn't have suggested a TEXTJOIN approach (while that made complete sense for your sample data and, really, most data sets, even large—but not enormous—ones). I'm not really sure how to approach something this size to do what you're trying to do. I'll let you know if anything comes to me.

Comment: thank you erik for your time and patience, it is the first time to me here so thant you also for the "good things to do" lesson.
I saw the problem of the 50k textjoin parameter but i thought i could be something manually upgradable (as the loop times paramether).
do you think the other answer can be better? i thought i was a little less flexible

Answer (score 2):

## step 1:

- convert the dataset to an actual value holder

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C3:J5="x", $C$2:$J$2, ))
  ```

[image]

## step 2:

- multiply combinations between **P** and **F** values
- drag formula over to the **`E`** column

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$9:$B$11&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(C9:C11)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C9:C11&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$9:$B$11))), CHAR(9))))),
   "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$9:$B$11&" "&C9:C11}, 1, 0), ))
  ```

[image]

## step 3:

- multiply combinations between **P&F** and **C** values
- drag formula over to the **`J`** column
- repeat logic for each **P&F** value (eg. **`G18`** and **`G22`**)

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($C$14:$C$17&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(G9:G11)), CHAR(9)))&" "&
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(G9:G11&CHAR(9), COUNTA($C$14:$C$17))), CHAR(9))))),
   "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$C$14:$C$17&" "&G9:G11}, 1, 0), ))
  ```

[image]

## step 4:

- extract all combinations and split them into separate cells

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY({G14:G25; H14:H25; I14:I25; J14:J25}, 
   "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc", 0), " "))
  ```

[image]

- ## [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NOCikpN4Q-pYlPJ56PnjpcevaQRl5nu9K2D_PtL442E/edit#gid=73051474)

## step 5: (only for hardcore long-formula-lovers)

- basically all of it can be packed up in one-cell solution

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY({
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not Null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,1)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,2)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,5)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,6)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )&" "&
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,7)}, 1, 0), ));
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )&CHAR(9)),
 COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8)&CHAR(9),
 COUNTA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE($B$3:$B&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)&CHAR(9), COUNTA($B$3:$B))), CHAR(9))))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0), ), {$B$3:$B&" "&INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,3)}, 1, 0), )&" "& 
 INDEX(IF($C$3:$J="x", $C$2:$J$2, ), ,8)}, 1, 0), ))}, 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc", 0), " "))
```

[image]

- ## [spreadsheet demo v2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NOCikpN4Q-pYlPJ56PnjpcevaQRl5nu9K2D_PtL442E/edit#gid=1898206087)

---

---

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you for your time ! and a really impressive job but Erik's solution is smaller and easier to appply!

Comment: hi Mark, how do you think that you answer would fit in a situation like this? how could you adapt it?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Npgpihw-1ulAHryqc0ONLtLbrz7cpfA2iAQfchvSjBA/edit#gid=0
feel free to edit

Comment: as you can read in the comment upside erik solution is smaller but limited by textjoin  50k characters (and as you can see i have way more) I passed over this problem changing all the words in numbers, sort them and then change them back again. This solution actually is quite heavy so I'm looking for something smaller and that can be done in one string. And more important i need no issues if i have to add more things to the chart.

Comment: thank you ! iactually the solution i find is that i changed all the words with numbers report the result there like 1-35-55, and then do a LOOKUP to check the number corrispondence and change the number in a word all this obviously with other sheet but the problem is that is quite heavy!

Comment: they are all the data i have for now but they can potentially be the double (this is the reason I need flexibility)

Comment: done. check your sheet. I hope you don't mind to mark my answer as the one which solved your issue. use this anywhere you want: `=IMPORTRANGE("1Npgpihw-1ulAHryqc0ONLtLbrz7cpfA2iAQfchvSjBA", "iii!J1:L")` I've put up a static data because this spreadsheet contains too many formulas and after you open it it will calculate only half of them and the other half will be errored out because of a timeout. to resolve this you will need to hunt down every formula outputing errors (usually on every sheet on row A101) and remove `=` and then again add `=` to refresh formulas.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nnbe.png